# How to modify .data values inside the .text segment in Mips?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, mips, code-generation

I have a global variable in Mips declared at the .data segment

```
.data
   globalVariable:  .word  10
```

How can I access and modify its content inside the .text segment?

Comment: What is "How can I access and modify its content inside the .text segment?" supposed to mean?

Comment: For instance, if you are developing a compiler, you should allocate global variables at the .data region, instead of keeping them into the stack. Following that approach, you must change the content of the .data values at runtime. That was what I was trying to ask. Sorry if wasn't clear

Comment: You can also allocate them from the heap.

Comment: Yeah but where does the text segmenr come into play?

Comment: Indeed you can, @FrankC. However, when developing a compiler, managing global variables allocated in the heap may become messy, inclusively when doing recursion.

Comment: I don't have the problem with my own self-hosted compiler. Are you referring to the output of the compiler (machine code) or the compiler management of it's own data (AST, IR, CFG, etc)?

Comment: @FrankC. Having the AST of the input code, I didn't manage properly the heap at the Mips code generation part when the code has function calls, because it changes the $fp reference. Therefore, in my development, only local variables are kept on the heap. The solution I found was allocating global variables at the .data segment. Obviously this was my fault, because it's perfectly workable to allocate all variables at the heap. However, my approach is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.data
   globalVariable:  .word  10

.text

   #access
   lw $a0, globalVariable 

   #modify
   la $a0, globalVariable #get address
   li $a1, 11 #new value
   sw $a1 0($a0) #save new value

   lw $a2, globalVariable  #get new value
```